# android-how to partially tint icons of bottomNavigationView?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-viewpager

I'm using a `viewPager` with a `bottomnavigationview` in my android app. how can I partially tint the icons of `bottomnavigationview` as the user swipes the `ViewPager`? Chrome has such UI for example:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use SegmentButton Library to do partially icon tint color change with smooth animation while tab changing

https://github.com/ceryle/SegmentedButton

Library allow customization as you required

Comment: thanks! but my first priority is handling it without a 3rd party library!

Comment: Okay. @Soheil. you can download library project and copy necessary code to your project .

Answer (score 1):

add following attribute to BottomNavigationView

```
app:itemIconTint="@color/bnv_item_selector"

  <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:itemBackground="@color/white"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/bnv_item_selector"
            app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationView.Active"
            app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationView"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_menu_text_selector"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />
```

bnv_item_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#6CBF51" />
    <item android:color="#E4E5ED"  />
</selector>
```

Hope this will help!!

Comment: it only gives a full tint to the selected icon, but does not partially tint as the user swipes.